# Different lines according to weights

Tags: riddle, knowledge

- When it was invented, different people were made to stand in lines according to their weights.
- In each line, people with equal weights were made to stand together.
- In the first line, there was a fat man.
- The weights of people standing in subsequent lines decreased.
- People standing in the eighth line were considered normal and healthy.

---

***What was this invention which is still widely used along with its modified versions?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invention is:

> the **[Snellen chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snellen_chart)**, used by ophthalmologists to measure visual acuity:
>
>  [image: Snellen chart example]
>  *<sub>Image source: Wikipedia</sub>*

*When it was invented, different people were made to stand in lines according to their weights.*
*In each line, people with equal weights were made to stand together.*

> Throughout this description, 'people' is used in place of **letters**. The Snellen chart consists of multiple rows/lines of block letters, grouped by size. In any given row, all letters are printed in the same size/weight font.

*In the first line, there was a fat man.*
*The weights of people standing in subsequent lines decreased.*

> The first line consists of one very large letter, i.e. *a fat man*. As you go down the chart, the font size/weight decreases.

*People standing in the eighth line were considered normal and healthy.*

> Being able to read the eighth line of the chart from the standard distance of 6 metres represents having '[20/20 vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_acuity)', the standard *considered normal and healthy*, and used as a reference point for diagnosing long- and short-sightedness.
>
>  The Snellen chart is still used today, albeit not necessarily in the exact same form as when it was first created.